# Can non wine liquor be used for the four cups at Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, liquor-beer, four-cups-wine, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, can one use liquor/non wine alcohol for the four cups on Passover? Or no, is wine a requirement? Is it a Machloket amongst the poskim?

Comment: **PLEASE**. Get in the habit of searching this site for five minutes before popping questions out. Repeated duplicates dilute the quality of this site.

Comment: Hard liquor -- assuming kosher for Pesach! -- is a really bad idea because at the bare minimum, you're drinking 3.4 ounces of the stuff on an empty stomach.